# I started to wear or I started wearing reading glasses

Tags: tense, infinitive-vs-gerund

When someone has just asked you about your reading glass. Can you say:

> I started **wearing** my reading glasses when I was 9.
>
> I started **to wear** my reading glasses when I was 9.

You are saying that, the start of you wearing reading glasses started when you were 9 years old.

Comment: *reading glasses* -- there should be an *s* at the end of *glasses*.

Comment: It sounds much more natural to this US English speaker to say **I started wearing**, but it's difficult to say exactly why, which makes this a good question.  In general, I think *I started Xing* means "I started performing the general action or recurring process of X" whereas "I started to X" means "I began a specific action of X".

Comment: John Arvin, if you ask two or three search engines to conjugate the verb *To wear*, which tenses do they show for *wearing* and for *to wear* and what does that leave unclear?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, Hello, I don't think the difference between them is searchable, that is, only real people can explain them accordingly. As I have just edited the wordings above as best as I can to achieve clarity, on the flip side, my question here is, which of them is "the appropriate tense" to use because they all seem the same.

Comment: Of course the difference between them is searchable, if you apply relevant search terms… If you can specify what search terms failed for you, someone might take the trouble to specify one that might work.

Answer (score 1):

A native would say

> I started **wearing** reading glasses when I was 9.

using "***my***" is redundant.

As @Stagdon points out *x-ing* may refer to something *habitual*.

> I have been **wearing** glasses...

consider the difference between

> I began **wearing** glasses when I was 9.
>   I began **to wear** glasees when I was 9.